# Using NODEjs express to upload images and retrieve them from amazon S3

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to retrieve images ive uploaded to an s3 bucket in an express server.

I have a user in s3 that im using the credentials of and am able to upload the images and see them in the bucket.

I have played around a bit with the permissions and i dont think thats where the issue is but i could be wrong, pretty new with this devops stuff.

so heres the process:

I upload the objects using a key that i generate and store in a database upon successful response from s3.

I am setting up the s3 instance as such:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: S3_USER_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: S3_USER_SECRET_KEY
});
```

then when i try to retrieve a url

```
 const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getImage',{
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key:recordKey,
        Expires: 60
    }).then( function(url){
        console.log(url);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(url);
```

that i can view the image from i get this error:

```
Error [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined

express_server  |     at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:130:61)

express_server  |     at Request.callListeners (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)

express_server  |     at callNextListener (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)

express_server  |     at /src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9

express_server  |     at finish (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)

express_server  |     at /src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9

express_server  |     at Credentials.get (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:127:7)

express_server  |     at getAsyncCredentials (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:398:24)

express_server  |     at Config.getCredentials (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:418:9)

express_server  |     at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:81:26) {

express_server  |   code: 'TypeError',

express_server  |   time: 2021-08-23T22:30:05.473Z

express_server  | }
```

what i believe i want to do is call S3, get url(s) based on the key(s) i send then i can manipulate the image display on the website from there.

I am using:

"aws-sdk": "^2.974.0"
"@aws-sdk/types": "^3.25.0",

and i am able to get the whole object using:

```
const objj = s3.getObject({Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key:keyFromDb }, function (err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);

        }else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

Let me know if youve been here before! or just know what to do THANKS!